# CPQ - SBQQ.QuoteAfter: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: cpq

I have a screen flow that is creating an opportunity and a quote. This flow works as expected in a lower environment. In the full sandbox, the flow fails with the below error:
This error occurred when the flow tried to create records:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: SBQQ.QuoteAfter: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object (System Code). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

I am setting the following values in the create quote element:
Account, Contact, Pricebook, PricebookID, Opportunity, Primary. Any ideas on what field is missing?